# Any guides for setting up basic services on clean VPS/dedicated server?

Tags: vps, dedicated-server

Do you know any guides to basically set up a server (VPS or dedicated) for working as (mainly) web server ?

I mean installing and setting up basic services like:

- apache with php, mod_rewrite, etc
- mysql
- FTP
- sendmail
- adding virtual host, domain, enabling wild card
- basic security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some good 'Perfect Server' tutorials over on HowToForge

They cover setting up most of the basic services and a GUI manager. The same author does them for a few OS' so pick whichever one you're most familiar with

CentOS - http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.5-x86_64-ispconfig-3
Fedora - http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-fedora-14-x86_64-ispconfig-3
Ubuntu - http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-11.04-ispconfig-3

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider should have a library of documentation to do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: Sure, let me google that for you... http://www.linode.com/community/ : https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help : http://community.godaddy.com/help?ci=44084 : And those are just the first three that I looked up. It's their business to provide a way for you to have a website. It's in the hosts best interest to make sure you have the resources you need. Seriously, if your host DOESN'T have basic guidelines to set up these services, that says a lot about the quality of your host, IMO.